# What types (next to string) can be passed from JavaScript to Swift inside WKScriptMessage?

Tags: javascript, swift, ios9, wkwebview

I know how to pass strings (e.g. from DOM text nodes) from JavaScript (inside an apps `WKWebView`) to Swift.

What other types are supported? For instance, could I pass DOM elements inside `WKScriptMessage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen any proper documentation for this. I have successfully put stuff in there that is `JSON` compatible.

I don't think a DOM element works. But just try it and see what you get back. You may have to turn it into a simpler object first in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkscriptmessage/1417901-body?language=objc), the allowed types are:

`NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, and `NSNull`.